# MacOS CoreData Fault Delete propagation prefetch fail

Tags: macos, sqlite, core-data

Two entities in a one to many relationship are deleted. Saving the context after the master entity is deleted causes a CoreData fault.

> 2020-05-13 11:55:48.460486-0400 TestCoreData[1325:99076] [error] fault: Delete propagation prefetching failed with exception: unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (#in IN $destinations)
>
> CoreData: fault: Delete propagation prefetching failed with exception: unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (#in IN $destinations)

Both relationships are optional with a Nullify delete rule. It appears as though CoreData is generating bad SQL.

[Archive Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEmnV.png)

[Media Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1QtD.png)

Sample code to create the error:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
NSError *error;
Archive *anArchive = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Archive" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
  anArchive.archiveID = @"archive";
  Media *theMedia = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Media" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
theMedia.mediaID = @"media";
theMedia.in = anArchive;
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:theMedia];
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) NSLog(@"error %@",error.localizedDescription);
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:anArchive];
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) NSLog(@"error %@",error.localizedDescription);
}
```

Comment: If the persistent store is XML based, the code works fine.

Comment: I suspect it might be a result of using "in" as the name of the relationship.  I would try a different name.

Comment: Thanks - that was the problem.